# Mantaflow not baking fluids

Tags: fluid-simulation

So, I've created a simple fluid scene in blender (Domain, Inflow object etc.) but, nothing happens.  I could do fluid with Mantaflow 2.81 Mantaflow branch back when I had it but, they've changed some things around in 2.81 beta which is the version I have. (two different versions of the beta haven't worked) **Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?**

Pls. download my .blend file for furthur reference. Thanks!

[image]

[image: this is the image]

Comment: Could you add an image?

Comment: Sure. I did. You can also download the .blend file

Comment: If you are using 2.81 it would be good to use the 2.81 branch. This is most likely the reason that you can't bake.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't clear. I'm using the blender 2.82 beta (two different versions of the beta haven't worked). I used to do the fluid perfectly back when I had 2.81 Mantaflow branch.